# Unable to mount Ext4 LVM (structure needs cleaning) but fsck reports it as clean

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lvm, ext4

Following a reboot I have an ext4 LVM that is unable to mount, returning the following message:

```
 mount(2) system call failed: Structure needs cleaning.
```

Most all advice I found so far to fix this problem is to run fsck, which I did, but it detected no problem and I'm still unable to mount.

```
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv0: clean, 1537462/1220943872 files, 8455482193/9767526400 blocks
```

If it helps, here is the output of dumpe2fs:

```
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /mnt/8tb_lvm
Filesystem UUID:          0c14f339-3435-4f7c-80fb-c8ffad46a4f1
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr dir_index filetype meta_bg extent 64bit flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              1220943872
Block count:              9767526400
Reserved block count:     410226390
Free blocks:              1312044207
Free inodes:              1219406410
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Group descriptor size:    64
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         4096
Inode blocks per group:   256
First meta block group:   1956
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Thu Dec 13 12:24:25 2018
Last mount time:          Fri Jan 11 13:47:11 2019
Last write time:          Tue Jan 29 00:04:50 2019
Mount count:              15
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Thu Dec 13 12:24:25 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          77 TB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      8e55a66d-33ac-4982-a09d-1f7676814d96
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0xb6b6782e
Journal features:         journal_incompat_revoke journal_64bit journal_checksum_v3
Journal size:             1024M
Journal length:           262144
Journal sequence:         0x00145a5d
Journal start:            0
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0x41317cb7
```

Any ideas on what to try next to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm strugling with exactly the same issue, and it happened exactly on the same day.
Are you using ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: I ran fsck with a backup superblock and rebooted. working now :)